# When is $n^{2015}+n+1$ prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> When is $n^{2015}+n+1$ prime, $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

I think this seems true only for $1$.

I tried to show that $4n-1,2n+1,2^{n+1}-1$ divides the given expression but didn't succeed. I have only thought about this through the way of modular arithmetic. Someone suggested to me to use the complex roots of this equation, but didn't specify how.  Are there any other results I can use for this problem(I may not know them)?

Please provide only hints if you do solve it. Thank you.

Comment: your term can be factorized!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
  n^{2015} +n+1 &=& n^{2015} -n^2+n^2+n+1  \\
   &=& n^2(n^{2013} -1) + n^2+n+1   \\
   &=& n^2(n^3-1)\underbrace{(n^{2010}+n^{2007}+...+n^3+1)}_a +n^2+n+1 \\
   &=& (n^2+n+1)(an^2(n-1)+1) \\
   &=&
\end{eqnarray*}
Since $n^2+n+1\geq 3$ this could be prime only if $an^2(n-1)+1 =1$ and this is only when $n=1$.

Comment: This would be a good contest-math Q at some level of competition.

Answer (score 14):

$2015\equiv 2\pmod{3}$ implies that $\Phi_3(n)=n^2+n+1$ is a divisor of $n^{2015}+n+1$, so...

Comment: What is that function?

Comment: @Adienl: the standard notation for cyclotomic polynomials: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial

Comment: Hi. I do not understand. Why does $2015\equiv 2\pmod{3}$ imply that $\Phi_3(n)=n^2+n+1$ is a divisor of $n^{2015}+n+1$?!

Comment: Because n raised to the 2015th power is congruent to n^2 mod n^3-1, hence n^2015 is congruent to n^2 mod n^2+n+1 too, since the last polynomial is a divisor of n^3-1.