# Factor $z^5 + z +1 =0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

The problem stated in the title is:

> Factor $z^5 + z + 1 = 0$
>   (naturally without the use of computers or calculators)

How do I go about solving this? Is there a more systematic approach than simply guessing a root and then applying polynomial division etc. ? Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $z^5 + z + 1 = f(z)g(z)$, then:

- $\deg f =1, \deg g=4$, or
- $\deg f =2, \deg g=3$

In both cases, you can try to determine the coefficients. Perhaps simplify things by first trying monic polynomials with independent term $1$.

The second case gives 
$$
(z^2+a z+1)(z^3+bz^2+c z+ 1) =
z^5 + (a + b)z^4 + (a b + c + 1)z^3 +  (a c + b + 1)z^2 + (a + c)z + 1
$$
Forcing the coefficients of $z^4,z^3,z^2$ to be zero and $a+c=1$, we get
$$z^5 + z + 1 = (z^2 + z + 1) (z^3 - z^2 + 1)$$

Comment: Ah OK, I've never seen this approach before! This looks quite good, thanks.

Comment: Thank you this very helpful! I suppose this technique breaks down though when the degree of the polynomial becomes large. But to be fair I guess very few techniques work for large degree polynomials. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
\begin{eqnarray}
z^5+z+1 &=& z^5-z^2+z^2+z+1\\
&=& z^2(z^3-1)+z ^2+z+1 \\
&=&...
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2389232/when-is-n2015n1-prime/2389270#2389270

Comment: Thank you! I am not sure how to go on right now, but the first thing I am thinking of is expressing the terms $z^2 + z + 1 $ as a geometric series $(z^3-1)/(z-1)$ and then factoring... Is this a good idea? I guess it at least established that we have a cube root of unity?!

Comment: Is this idea of "creatively adding zero" as you did a general approach. What told you that adding $z^2$ would be helpful? Thank you

Comment: Yes, but not everything will work. You have to have some personal experience to see what to add.

Comment: I see. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If $z=w$ where $w$ is a complex cube root of unity

$z^5+z+1=0$

Comment: How did you find that result? Did you guess? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a perfectly valid hint (though it could have been a comment...)

Comment: @wittbluenote, This works for $$z^{3m+2}+z^{3n+1}+z^{3r}$$

Comment: @SebastianSchoennenbeck, This is a very common phenomenon. I don't mind until I find something really wrong in my post

Comment: Thanks! I suppose you argued like @John Watson...